# How to remove hyphen from column in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to delete all `-` from the elements in a column of a pyspark dataframe.

so I have:

```
111-345-789   
123654980   
144-900-888  
890890890  
....
```

and I want to have a column that is:

```
111345789   
123654980   
144900888   
890890890
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
df.withColumn("col", F.regexp_replace("col", "-", "")).show()

#+---------+
#|      col|
#+---------+
#|111345789|
#|123654980|
#|144900888|
#|890890890|
#+---------+
```

Or `replace`:

```
df.withColumn("col", F.expr("replace(col, '-', '')")).show()
```